# Catched Exceptions don't get logged in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, exception, logging

In my Controller, I have this snippet

```
        try {
            $content = $content->loadAndGetContent($id);
        } catch (UnknownContentTypeException $e) {
            abort(500);
        }
```

**UnknownContentTypeException.php**

```
<?php


namespace App\Exceptions;


use Exception;
use Log;

/**
 * Throw this if the content type of data cannot be determined
 * @package App\Exceptions
 */
class UnknownContentTypeException extends Exception
{

    public function report(Exception $e)
    {
        Log::error('----- CONTENT TYPE ' . $e->getMessage() . ' DOES NOT EXIST!');
    }
}
```

The `UnknownContentTypeException` gets catched and triggers `abort(500)`. However, in my logs only the  `HttpException` from `abort(500)` appears. What do I need to do if I want both exceptions to be logged?

Comment: If you catch it, it wont get logged, it gets logged if you dont catch it

Comment: I am not a laravel guy but I think in catch block you must call report($e); for the function to trigger.

Comment: Just remove your try/catch block and it will work

Comment: @MuhammadTashfeen Thank you. This is what I was looking for.